# No logs from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not able to read logs from an FirebaseMessagingService instance. I don't see any log entries printed to LogCat.

Breakpoints also don't work. `putExtra` call doesn't fire -- extras always `null` in my MainActivity.

What could be a reason for such behaviour?

It feels like a default superclass `FirebaseMessagingService` instance is being called somehow. My custom code seems to be completely ignored.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.


        Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent send notification");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .build();
        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent");

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fcm", "test");
        intent.putExtra("notification", true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        intent.setAction(uniqueID);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
//                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        MainActivity mainActivity = AppDelegate.shared().mainActivity;
        if (mainActivity != null) {
            NotificationsViewmodel notificationsViewmodel = mainActivity.notificationsViewmodel;
            if (notificationsViewmodel != null) {
                notificationsViewmodel.actionGetNotifications();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
        <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

No logs (no matter what do I try to select in this window):

[image]

Files in Android project:

[image]

And same files on disk:
[image]

Configuration:
[image]

Data:
[image]

Comment: what does your message payload look like from your server

Comment: Try looking for any error in your LogCat. But first, have you followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) setup tutorial before?

Comment: FCM messages come from the server successfully. If I click a notification message from drawer or top of the screen I get MainActivity opened. I send 3 key-value pairs from the server using FCM UI.

Comment: I also have Firebase configured (see original post update), I do get an FCM key correctly.

Comment: so onMessageReceived is getting called?

Comment: how do you send data? from firebase console?

Comment: @tyczj I don't see any logs from onMessageReceived. I don't think it is called.

Comment: @PavelPoley yes, from console (web UI)

Comment: If onMessageReceived does not get called then you are not sending the notification correctly. For that to get called you have to use only the data payload and not `notification`. The console does not do data payloads and will only send a regular notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `onMessageReceived(...)` will not get called if the app is in background or killed state, when the message is sent through Firebase Console.

But when the message is sent via API (perform a POST to the following URL : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send ), the method `onMessageReceived(…)` will get invoked.

To send a message using API, you can use a tool called AdvancedREST Client it is chrome extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

For more details this tutorial http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/

Comment: It's not called while the app is in the foreground either. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are cheeking when the activity after onResume() and before onPause?

Comment: Your advice on rest API usage did help. I have some null ptr issue which is being correctly logged now.

Comment: if you mean notification drawer - status bar,  you need to create a custom notification with notification manager in you onMessageReceived(...) method

Comment: Could you take a look? I reworded my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153056/firebase-cloud-messaging-custom-data-in-notification